# Why is my /home separate from /?

Tags: linux, partition, hard-disk, disk-usage

I was confused why I was getting out of space errors so I ran `df` and saw this:

```
[me@fedlap /]$ df -h
Filesystem                     Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
rootfs                          43G  9.4G   34G  23% /
...
/dev/mapper/vg_fedlap-lv_root   43G  9.4G   34G  23% /
...
/dev/mapper/vg_fedlap-lv_home   22G   21G   12M 100% /home
```

The partition is about 69GB so the sum of everything is correct, but I have no idea why `/home` is allocated this way. Gparted shows one 500MB ext4 partition and one lvm2 69Gb partition. What exactly is `/dev/mapper` and is there a way to remove it?

I have no idea what the ratio of installed programs to user data will be in the future so I have no need to separate these on a single user system. This is on Fedora 16 with one physical disk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`/dev/mapper` is used by [LVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_Volume_Manager_%28Linux%29). You cannot remove it unless you remove LVM, but this is not a trivial task; if you insist, it is easiest to just back up your data, reinstall, and restore your data.

Comment: Is there a way to resize? If it needs a reinstall I'd rather wait until F17 is released.

Comment: Enlarging a volume can be done while the system is running, but you'll need to take it offline in order to reduce. See the [LVM how-to](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/LVM-HOWTO/) for details.

Answer (score 2):

Your system is using the [Logical Volume Manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_Volume_Manager_%28Linux%29) to manage the disk space.

One advantage of using LVM is that, without reinstalling your system, you can do things as changing the size of *logical partitions* or as adding new disks.

In any case, **backup your data**. To resize partitions with LVM is quite easy but this is the first time you do such a thing, so be careful.

Next time you install a system using LVM, you should keep the partitions as smaller as you can. Keep as much free space as you can in the *volume group*. This way you can easily increase the partition when you need more space.

There are many ways you can proceed according to your installation details:

1. Do you have some un-partitioned disk space on your system? If yes, you can:

   - create a new lvm partition (a *physical volume* in LVM jargon).
   - add it to your *volume group* vg_fedlap (using `vgextend` command).
   - fall back to point 2 of this list.
2. Do you have some free space in your *volume group* `vg_fedlap`?

   - run `vgdisplay vg_fedlap` and check for *Free  PE / Size*. If zero, go to point 2 of this list.
   - use `lvextend` to extend your *logical volume* `lv_home`
   - extend your file system to the new *logical volume* size by `resize2fs` or `resize_reiserfs` according to your file system type.
3. If you have no free space, You need to [shrink your root filesystem](http://equivocation.org/node/103).

   - start your system by a [fedora installation disk](http://fedoraproject.org/en/get-fedora-options) in [rescue mode](http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/16/html/Installation_Guide/ap-rescuemode.html#s1-rescuemode-boot).
   - shrink your file system to the new desidered size by `resize2fs` or `resize_reiserfs` according to your file system type.
   - use `lvreduce` to reduce the `lv-root` size.
   - reboot your system.
   - now you have free space, go to point 2 of this list.